# Need help developing a proper print method for this Java program

Tags: java

This program takes integers from user input and puts them in a collection. It then prints the positive values first, then the negative values, and doesn't print repeated numbers. It stops asking for input once the user enters 0. Here is the code:

```
public class Intcoll2
{
   private int[] c;
   private int[] d;
   private int howmany = 0;

   public Intcoll2()
   {
        c = new int[500];
   }

   public Intcoll2(int i)
   {
        c = new int[i]
   }

   public void insert(int i)
   {
        if (i > 0)
        {
             int j = 0;
             while ((j <= howmany) && (c[j] != i)) j++;
             if (j == howmany)
             {
                   if (j == c.length - 1)
                   {
                        d = new int[2*c.length];
                        for (int k = 0; k<c.length; i++){
                            d[k] = c[k];
                        }
                        c = d;
                   }
                   c[j] = i; c[j + 1] = 0;
             }
             howmany++;
         }
    }

    public int get_howmany()
    {
          int j=0, howmany=0;

          while (c[j]!=0) {howmany++; j++;}
          return howmany;
    }
```

Now my current print method looks like this:

```
   public void print()
   {
        int j = 0;
        System.out.println();
        while (j <= howmany)
        {
            System.out.println(c[j]); j++;
        }
   }
```

But when I try to use that in my client, it only prints out zeros. Any help with what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, 1 thing I can see, is that you never add the argument of `insert` to the array `c`. Your for-loop will also run infinitely if `c.length > 0` because you don't increment `k`

Comment: No wait, you do in `c[j] = i` I got confused because `i` is usually an index. You could rename `i` to something like `toInsert`, makes it more readable.

Comment: Do you ever call the method `insert(int i)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your class and rewrote it in a more legible manner. I didn't test it but I'm confident it works. You can check it out and hopefully understand what's happening. Hope this helps!

```
public class IntCollection2 {

    private int[] collection; // A large allocation, not neccessarily filled up.
    private int currentSize; // The number of spots currently filled in the collection.

    public IntCollection2() {

        collection = new int[500];
        currentSize = 0;

    }

    public IntCollection2(int size) {

        collection = new int[size];
        currentSize = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Inserts a new element into the internal array. If the current array is filled up,
     * a new array double the size of the current one is allocated.
     * @param element An int to insert into the collection. Must not be '0'.
     * @return True if the element was successfully inserted, false if the element was
     *         equal to '0' and was ignored.
     */
    public boolean insert(int element) {

        if (element != 0) {

            if (currentSize < collection.length - 1) {

                collection[currentSize] = element;

            } else {

                int[] newCollection = new int[collection.length * 2];

                for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) {

                    newCollection[i] = collection[i];

                }

                newCollection[currentSize] = element;
                collection = newCollection;

            }

            currentSize++;
            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Not actually necessary because the class automatically updates its currentSize
     * every time a new element is inserted.
     * @return The current number of filled spots in the internal array.
     */
    public int getCurrentSize() {

        int size = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.length && collection[i] != 0; i++) {
            size++;
        }

        return size;

    }

    /**
     * Prints out all the elements currently in the collection, one on each line.
     */
    public void print() {

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) {

            System.out.println(collection[i]);

        }

    }

}
```

FYI: this class just prints out every element in the collection, in order. You mentioned something about printing positive then negative values, but I leave that to you.

EDIT: I'm guessing you're brand new to programming, so I just want to clarify exactly what a collection is. An **array** is an ordered list of elements. When you create an array, the computer sets aside a bit of memory to hold exactly the number of elements you told it to. You cannot change the size of an existing array. A **collection** is basically a wrapper around an array. It makes a bigger array than it needs to hold its elements, and when its array becomes full, it allocates a new, bigger one that can hold more elements.

Answer (score 3):

An answer that you were probably not looking for, but still on the only **real** answer you should care about.

Your problem is not that somewhere in that code a bug is hiding. The problem is that your code is **confusing** beyond limits:

- Dont use single-character variable names.
- The constructor that takes an int ... creates an **empty** array!
- Dont say "collection" when you are using arrays.
- Dont give fields and local variables the **same** name.

Seriously: understanding this mess is mainly complicated and hard because you wrote code that is **hard** to read.

Now you are asking other people to debug such complicated code that you (the author who created it!) do not understand in the first place.

Instead, you might throw this whole thing away. And slowly write it again;  but in a way that isn't at all confusing to the reader.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I agree it is confusing code and it was written by my professor with some tweaks made by me. Also I made a small edit: the constructor should not create an empty array, it should create one with int i.

Comment: I see. Hint: simply use System.out.println() statements to print whenever you make changes to the array, and so on.

Comment: Additionally, use for-loops whenever you iterate through an array. A while-loop should only be used for something that happens continually while a condition is satisfied, like a method to update a loading screen. For example, in your print() method, use for(int j = 0; j < howMany; j++) { System.out.println(c[j]); }.